# Async NSURLConnection triggering other Async NSURLConnection: what is the best way of doing this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

this is an open question aiming at understanding what is the best practice or the most common solution for a problem that I think might be common.

Let's say I have a list of URLs to download; the list is itself hosted on a server, so I start  a NSURLConnection that downloads it. The code in connectionDidFinishLoading will use the list of URLs to instantiate one new NSURLConnection, asynchronously, per each URL; this in turn will trigger even more NSURLConnections, and so on - until there are no more URLs. See it as a tree of connections.

**What is the best way to detect when all connections have finished?**

I'm aiming the question to iOS7, but comments about other versions are welcome.

Comment: Just when all are finished? Or you want just one running at a time? What have you considered doing (and what do you see the pros and cons as)?

Comment: Just when all are finished. These are all async NSURLConnections, so nothing can be said about when/in what order they will be executed. I'm not an expert, so the only method I've had some experience with is using GCD with dispatch_async, so that I can monitor the queue. In this case, probably, dispatch_group_async. But as I said, I'm not an expert and would like to know what the options are. (

Comment: BTW, if you're not supporting background session, you can use GCD to keep track of whether you're done or not, but with async requests you'd probably manually `dispatch_group_enter` when you create requests, `dispatch_group_leave` in their completion handlers. Then `dispatch_group_notify` can trigger when the group is complete. Having said that, when doing a bunch of requests, simply knowing that you're "done" is usually inadequate (you often like to know how far along you are or which are still being downloaded), so I'd go back to that "list of pending requests" approach discussed elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. In terms of triggering the subsequent downloads after you retrieve the list from the server, just put the logic to perform those subsequent downloads inside the completion handler block (or completion delegate method) of the first request.
2. In terms of downloading a bunch of files, if targeting iOS 7 and later, you might consider using `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection`.

   - First, the downloading of files with a nice modest memory footprint is enabled by initiating "download" tasks (rather than "data" tasks).
   - Second, you can do the downloads using a background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, which will let the downloads continue even if the user leaves the app. See the [Downloading Content in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) section of the *App Programming Guide for iOS.* There are a lot of i's that need dotting and t's that need crossing if you do this, but it's a great feature to consider implementing.

   See [WWDC 2013 What's New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=705) for an introduction to `NSURLSession`. Or see the relevent chapter of the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1).
3. In terms of keeping track of whether you're done, as Wain suggests, you can just keep track of the number of requests issued and the number of requests completed/failed, and in your "task completion" logic, just compare these two numbers, and initiate the "all done" logic if the number of completions matches the number of requests. There are a bunch of ways of doing this, somewhat dependent upon the details of your implementation, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea.

Comment: Rob, @wain, great points! In terms of keeping track, though, I suppose I need to use a synchronised counter?

Comment: Yep. Or, given that you'll often want to be able to show the user the progress of outstanding requests, I'd generally have some mutable array of pending requests (and then, when you remove the last item, you can trigger the "all done" logic). Also, `NSURLSession` has method for enumerating pending requests, so you can sometimes get away with using what it already provides. It just depends upon the particular needs of your app. But I think you got the basic idea.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using GCD you should consider using `NSOperationQueue`. You should also limit the number of concurrent operations, certainly on mobile devices, to perhaps 4 so you don't flood the network with requests.

Now, the number of operations on the queue is the remaining count. You can add a block to the end of each operation to check the queue count and execute any completion logic.

Comment: Yep, or you can add a "completion operation" to your queue, which you make dependent upon each of the network requests. Note that you probably want to do an asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass, though, otherwise these asynchronous requests will not respect the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of the queue, nor will dependencies work properly.

Comment: Apple recommends against using concurrency to handle network tasks. There are a number of system classes (NSURLConnection, NSURLSession, etc.) That handle async downloading for you, without either the complexity or system resources required to do this yourself.

Comment: @DuncanC I respectfully disagree. I'd like to see references to Apple advising against `NSOperation` implementations. Yes, it would be silly to use GCD to dispatch `NSURLConnection` to background queue, but operations are excellent way to encapsulate concurrent requests, queues let you control the degree of concurrency, etc. I think Wain's observation is spot on if using `NSURLConnection`. Furthermore, elsewhere, you recommend AFNetworking, a `NSOperation`-based `NSURLConnection` implementation, so I'm surprised to see you advise against it here.

Comment: @Rob, most of the posts I've seen to this effect have been on the Apple developer forums, by Apple engineers who are well qualified to make the judgement. I can't find the "smoking gun" thread I'm looking for, but this one is pretty close: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/9606?start=0&tstart=0 Be sure to tread all of "Quinn the Eskimo"'s ("Eskimo1") posts in that thread.

Comment: The gist is that threads are expensive in terms of system resources, and so if there is a solution (like the async support in NSURLConnection and NSURLSession) that provides async networking using already-allocated system resources, you should use that. As for AFNetworking, I haven't looked at how it's implemented, just that it seems (on the outside) like a well thought-out, polished framework for doing networking.)

Answer (score 1):

As Rob says in his answer you might want to consider NSURLSession rather than doing this yourself. It has a number of advantages.

Other options are building your own download manager class, or using a ready-made third party framework like AFNetworking. I've only worked with AFNetworking a little bit but from what I've seen its elegant, powerful, and easy to use.

Our company wrote an async download manager class based on NSURLConnection for a project that predates both AFNetworking and NSURLSession. It's not that hard, but it isn't as flexible as either NSURLSession or AFNetworking.